# Question regarding RFC7296 (IKEv2) PRF+

Tags: key-generation

In RFC 7296, in section [2.13](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-2.13)

What do the "K", "S", and T# represent?

And my follow-up question is, in section [2.14](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296#section-2.14)

What would be the K, S, and T# equivalent in

> {SK_d | SK_ai | SK_ar | SK_ei | SK_er | SK_pi | SK_pr} = prf+
> (SKEYSEED, Ni | Nr | SPIi | SPIr)

Thanks !